GROUP BY de SQL me ordena de forma equivocada los numeros correlativos
Estoy realizando una consulta para un reporte donde necesito agrupar mis registros en la misma fecha desde el numero mínimo hasta el máximo pero cuando creo una tabla temporal para crear mis Rangos y colocar una Bandera al numero mínimo(campo BIn) los números se ordenan de forma incorrecta de la siguiente forma[1,10,11,2,3...] lo cual esta mal, he revisado y creo que el problema se genera cuando agrego el Group By debido a que utilizo un LEAD y un LAG.
Se ordena de esta forma

Adjunto el código que estoy utilizando.
SELECT Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial, corr as corrF,Final,
case when final is null and BFin is null then Inicial end as ini,
case when  (LEAD(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial +1  OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial -1 ) THEN Final end as Fin,
case when (LAG(Inicial,1,-1) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial -1) /*OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial +1 */ THEN 'I' END AS BIn,
BFin
INTO #RANGOS
FROM #LIMITES
GROUP BY Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial,Final,BFin
order by Inicial

Alguien podría brindarme su valiosa ayuda aconsejándome que hacer para poder resolver esto, gracias de antemano.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Tu problema es que corr "se ve" como un numero, porque parecen ser numeros, pero obviamente no es un numero, es una cadena... si lo trasformas a numero se va a ordenar como vos queres...

Leí tu pregunta varias veces y no me queda claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. Entiendo el problema con el ordenamiento pero, qué resultado final es el que esperas obtener? Estoy seguro que ayudaría a la explicación una tablita de la salida que esperas obtener con los datos que ya muestras en la pregunta. Además, vendría genial que esos datos estén en texto plano y no en imagenes. Saludos.

@gbianchi tenias toda la razón estaba manejando como texto mi campo corr, realice el cambio en mis tablas temporales y ya quedo bien. excelente, gracias por la ayuda.

El problema esta es que ese campo que es texto y esa es forma natural de ordenar y si lo quieres tratar con un ordenamiento numérico debes hacerle CAST, te coloco las dos DBMS que utilizo.
Aquí el código para MySQL:
SELECT Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial, corr as corrF,Final,
case when final is null and BFin is null then Inicial end as ini,
case when  (LEAD(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial +1  OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial -1 ) THEN Final end as Fin,
case when (LAG(Inicial,1,-1) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial -1) /*OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial +1 */ THEN 'I' END AS BIn,
BFin
INTO #RANGOS
FROM #LIMITES
GROUP BY Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial,Final,BFin
order by CAST(Inicial AS UNSIGNED);

Aquí el código para SQL SERVER:
SELECT Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial, corr as corrF,Final,
case when final is null and BFin is null then Inicial end as ini,
case when  (LEAD(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial +1  OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) = Inicial -1 ) THEN Final end as Fin,
case when (LAG(Inicial,1,-1) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial -1) /*OR LAG(Inicial,1,0) OVER (order by idSerie) != Inicial +1 */ THEN 'I' END AS BIn,
BFin
INTO #RANGOS
FROM #LIMITES
GROUP BY Fecha,idSerie,corr,Inicial,Final,BFin
order by CAST(Inicial AS INT);

OJO Tambien lo puedes utilizar en tus CASE:
 WHEN (LEAD(CAST(Inicial AS INT), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY idSerie) = CAST(Inicial AS INT) + 1 OR 
              LAG(CAST(Inicial AS INT), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY idSerie) = CAST(Inicial AS INT) - 1) 


Si que especifica cuál es el DBMS, la pregunta tiene las etiquetas [tag:sql-server] y [tag:sql-server-2019]

Tus datos se están ordenando así porque son números en formato texto 1,10,11,12,2,21..
Lo puedes corregir añadiendo en el order by : CONVERT o CAST
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

Modifica el final de tu consulta SQL así:
order by CAST(Inicial AS INT);

